# Php query based on selected/default dropdown and output on same page

Tags: php, mysql

I have managed to create dropdown from Mysql column and also get query result with get method but here webpage is directed to other page when hit button. 
I am looking to get query output with some default option set in dropdown when page loads or want query result on same page reloading it again when user changes option.

Any help will be appreciated.

Code on main page for dropdown:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT nx_version FROM workflow1 ORDER BY id");
echo "<form action='process.php' method='get'>";
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<p></p>";
echo "<center>";
echo "<strong> Select Base Verison To Compare With : </strong>";
echo "<select name=nx_version>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($nx_version);
    $nx_version = $row['nx_version']; 
    echo '<option value>'.$nx_version.'</option>';
}

echo "</select>";
echo "&nbsp;<button type='submit'>See items</button>";
echo "</center>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
echo "<p></p>"; 
echo "<form>";
```

Code I wrote when hit button and gives query output (in process.php):

```
$nx_version = $_GET['nx_version']; // The name attribute of the select
$query = "SELECT step1 FROM workflow1 WHERE nx_version = '$nx_version' ORDER BY id DESC";
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$array = Array();            
while($result1 = $query1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $result1['step1'];
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

process.php file should be like this -

```
<?php
session_start();
$nx_version = $_GET['nx_version']; // The name attribute of the select

$query = "SELECT step1 FROM workflow1 WHERE nx_version = '$nx_version' ORDER BY id DESC";
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$array = Array();

while($result1 = $query1->fetch_assoc()){
$array[] = $result1['step1'];
}
$_SESSION['data'] = $array;
// storing the data as session
header("location:main_page.php");
?>
```

Now get back the data from session in your main page by adding this-

```
$array = $_SESSION['data'];
```

Comment: I have added second line of code in main php file but getting error as I load main page: `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION`

Comment: Above error resolved by adding `<?php session_start();?>` after `<html>` tag. But nothing happens when hit button on main page. I forgot to mention while posting main question that when I used to hit button address bar had `...\nx_version=` that is button click wasn't sending selected/active option.

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad the value tag is empty in <option value="">

Comment: remove the word value

Comment: Wow, @Devansh Goyal, now it's working, but still have some queries. 1. When I reload the page default 1st dropdown value is set but result is for old selected option. How to refersh that for default option? 2. When I select option other than default and hit button, result is displayed but select option is reset, how can I set it selected upon hitting button? 3. When there are 2 entries for the same `version` both entries are in result. I want only latest.